# Script not running jquery .each

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a snippet from a puzzle game I'm trying to develop. The problem is it stops working after `each()` of jquery is called. Please help me figure out the problem. Thanks in advance.

```
    function setTotalInPositionPieces()
    {
        $("#board").children('div').each(function(index, element) {
            if(testInPosition(element))
            {
                ++totalInPositionPieces;
                $(element).attr("data-inPositionStatus", '1');
            }
        });

    /* The script does not from here, onward. Please tell 
me what is the problem.*/

        if(totalInPositionPieces == totalPieces)
        {
            $("#messageBox").text("Puzzle Solved!");
        }
    }
```

`totalInPositionPieces` and `totalPieces` are global variables.

Comment: What error console says? And btw you're showing us now much of your code.

Comment: have you tried sending var results = $("#board").children('div'); to console to see if you actually have elements in your collection?

Comment: Nitpick: Use [`data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/). So it would be `$(element).data("inPositionStatus", '1');` Also you could write `$("#board").children('div')` as `$("#board>div')`

Comment: Where is `totalInPositionPieces` reset/defined?

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: Not sure if it's related to your problem, but data attributes must be all lowercase. [source](http://bit.ly/9Udecy).

Comment: `totalPieces` and `totalInPositionPieces` both are global variables.

Answer (score 2):

you should define the `var totalInPositionPieces` outside the `each` function to be reachable in the scope of any other function or outside of it.
same for `totalPieces`. Where do you define it?

Explore this stuff too: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/

Comment: `totalPieces` and `totalInPositionPieces` both are global variables.

Answer (score 0):

```
function setTotalInPositionPieces()
    {
        var list = $("#board").children('div');
        var totalInPositionPieces = 0;

        $.each(list, function(index, element) {
            if(testInPosition(element))
            {
                ++totalInPositionPieces;
                $(element).attr("data-inPositionStatus", '1');
            }
        });

        if(totalInPositionPieces == totalPieces)
        {
            $("#messageBox").text("Puzzle Solved!");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Care to venture an explanation for this?